Svelte list crossfade randomly misplaces elements
I have a list which I want to animate so that when an item is selected, it floats to top and the rest fly out. On reselecting the element it floats back to its place and others fly back in.
Using this crossfade demo I was able to produce a pretty solid version:
REPL
However, I noticed that the elements sometimes aren't returned to their original position and only a subsequent re-animating might fix it. I am pretty sure this is because my crossfade function needs more sophisticated handling (or that I should use just regular transition instead?) but I am unsure how exactly.
<script>
  import { flip } from 'svelte/animate'
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store'
  import { crossfade, fly } from 'svelte/transition'

  const ACTIONS = [
    { key: 'blue' },
    { key: 'green' },
    { key: 'yellow' },
    { key: 'purple' },
    { key: 'orange' },
    { key: 'red' },
  ]
  const selectedAction = writable(null)
  let shownActions = ACTIONS.map(a => a)

  const [send, receive] = crossfade({
    fallback(node, _params) {
      return fly(node, { x: -800, duration: 600 })
    }
  })

  function selectAction(action) {
    if ($selectedAction === action) {
      shownActions = ACTIONS.map(a => a)
      selectedAction.update(v => {
        if (v === action || action === undefined) {
          return null
        } else {
          return action
        }
      })
    } else {
      shownActions = ACTIONS.filter(a => a.key === action)
      selectedAction.update(v => {
        if (v === action || action === undefined) {
          return null
        } else {
          return action
        }
      })
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    }
  }
</script>

<ul>
{#each shownActions as action (action)}
  <li
    class={`${$$props.class || ''}`}
    animate:flip={{ duration: 600 }}
    in:receive={{ key: action.key }}
    out:send={{ key: action.key }}
  >
    <button on:click={e => selectAction(action.key)}>{action.key}</button>
  </li>
{/each}
</ul>

<style lang="scss">
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    li {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    button {
        margin-right: 1rem;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    }
</style>

EDIT: So in the end I discarded the list out animation, leaving just the sliding effect for the individual item. It just feels less noisy that way. Now that I upgraded my svelte version, it seems the animations themselves feel less buggier — there were some problems with the animated elements not being reset properly, making them appear squished.
Animations for both in/out for all items:
{#each shownActions as action (action)}
  <li
    class={`${$$props.class || ''}`}
    animate:flip={{ duration: 500 }}
    in:fly={{ delay: 0, duration: 500 }}
  >
    <div
      class={`${$$props.class || ''}`}
      in:receive={{ key: action.key }}
      out:send={{ key: action.key }}
    >
      <button on:click={e => selectAction(action.key)}>{action.key}</button>
    </div>
  </li>
{/each}

No fly-out animation for the other list items, my preferred choice:
{#each shownActions as action (action)}
  <li
    class={`${$$props.class || ''}`}
    animate:flip={{ duration: 500 }}
    in:receive={{ key: action.key }}
  >
    <button on:click={e => selectAction(action.key)}>{action.key}</button>
  </li>
{/each}


There's a related open issue https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4910

It looks like the issue pops when you are clicking before the animation is over. You could wait for the animation to end using transition events. But there's also an issue with the position of the elements during the transition. I had better results when using a child div inside li elements and a slide animation on li :
{#each shownActions as action (action)}
  <li
        in:slide={({deylay: 0, duration: 300})}
        out:slide={({deylay: 600, duration: 300})}
  >
        <div
            class={`${$$props.class || ''}`}
            in:receive={{ key: action.key }}
            out:send={{ key: action.key }}
        >
            <button on:click={e => selectAction(action.key)}>{action.key}</button>
        </div>
  </li>
{/each}

demo

Thank you! That's a great example, it seems using animate with transition is the culprit. However if you switch the fly x coordinate positive, you'll see that the items now also slide upwards as they fly out which looks somewhat weird. But I suppose it's better than bugging out

What is annoying is that the crossfade transition wont trigger for the element, even with the keyed block, that was picked so you can't if-else your way out of it with single transition.

Okay, after a long while I finally came back to this. I accepted your solution @Brewal as it was the closest to what I wanted. However, to me the out animation for the whole item list is actually quite jarring so I decided to leave it out with just the item sliding into position.

Looks like this can be solved by

seperating the animate:flip and the transitions on seperate elements. (Since the elements just vanish and don't move to a different 'location/container' the crossfade isn't needed)
Making the <ul> a flex element to prevent 'collapsing' of the stack (visible with a longer duration and clicking on a lower element / related question)
blocking action while transition is playing

REPL
<script>
    import { flip } from 'svelte/animate'
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store'
    import { crossfade, fly } from 'svelte/transition'

    const ACTIONS = [
        { key: 'blue' },
        { key: 'green' },
        { key: 'yellow' },
        { key: 'purple' },
        { key: 'orange' },
        { key: 'red' },
    ]

    let animating = false

    const selectedAction = writable(null)
    let shownActions = ACTIONS.map(a => a)

    function selectAction(action) {
        if(animating === true) return

        if ($selectedAction === action) {
            shownActions = ACTIONS.map(a => a)
            selectedAction.update(v => {
                if (v === action || action === undefined) {
                    return null
                } else {
                    return action
                }
            })
        } else {
            shownActions = ACTIONS.filter(a => a.key === action)
            selectedAction.update(v => {
                if (v === action || action === undefined) {
                    return null
                } else {
                    return action
                }
            })
            window.scrollTo({
                top: 0,
                behavior: 'smooth'
            })
        }
    }
</script>

<ul>
    {#each shownActions as action (action)}
        <li
            class={`${$$props.class || ''}`}
            animate:flip={{ duration: 600 }}
            >
            <div
                in:fly={{ x: -800, duration: 600 }}
                out:fly={{ x: -800, duration: 600 }}
                on:introstart={() => animating = true}
                on:outrostart={() => animating = true}
                on:introend={() => animating = false}
                on:outroend={() => animating = false}
                >
                <button on:click={e => selectAction(action.key)}>{action.key}</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    {/each}
</ul>

<style lang="scss">
    ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        list-style: none;
    }
    li {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    button {
        margin-right: 1rem;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    }
</style>

